# How do I set the values in x that are above the mean to their difference from the mean in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I set the values in x that are above the mean to their difference from the mean.

```
x = [3 15 9 12 -1 0 -12 9 6 1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = [3 15 9 12 -1 0 -12 9 6 1];
m = mean(x);
idx = (x>m);
x(idx) = x(idx) - m;
```

Comment: Thanks Amro .. you are a lifesaver.. Shokran!!